# Redundancy in dependency management

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm very new to Maven. When creating a uber jar file in Maven, we create a jar file containing all of the other jar files that we depend on. However it seems to me that there could be a lot of redundancy created when we do not have control over those other dependencies. For example:

1. if an application "A" has dependency "foo"
2. dependency "foo" has dependency "bar"
3. application "A" also uses dependency "bar"

is Maven smart enough to recognize that "bar" is used in "foo" and references it if it has the exact version number or does it add an extra copy? I know that maven shade plug-in obfuscates the dependency from other jars so my intuition tells me reusability is preferred over redundancy for this scenario. Is this the case? Are there any common practices to help avoid redundancies?

Comment: Maven will resolve one version for "bar" via dependency mediation - https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#transitive-dependencies

Comment: Maven should be smart enough to realize that the same dependency is used multiple times and should evict all but one - but the rules may yield a different result than intended as it would keep the most specific dependency even if it is the older one (i.e. for A it would be `A->bar` and not `A->foo->bar`). This on the other hand might result in other problems like code not being compatible at runtime etc. (I'd thus like to see conflict managers like Apache Ivy's make it to Maven).

Comment: Thank you Nick and Thomas. Your explanations were very helpful.